# convergence of sequence $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

is the sequence $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{(2+a_n)}$ convergent with $a_n=1$?

using induction i was able to prove $a_n<5$ (I choose $5$ randomly) for all n
and also a increasing sequence Which also I proved using induction.
So can I say since a monotonic bounded sequence are convergent can we say above sequence is convergent?

My induction for boundedness
$a_1=1<5$ $a_2=\sqrt(3)<5$

let the statement be true for $1,...n$,
$a_n<5$
$ \implies a_n+2<5+2 \implies \sqrt{a_n+2}<\sqrt{7}\implies a_{n+1}<5$
is this correct?

Comment: If you correctly proved that the sequence is monotonic then yes.

Comment: and is my proof for showing bounded above is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof that $a$ is bounded is true, but we can make it a bit of simpler.

Also you need to prove that $a$ increases.

By using induction we'll prove that $a_n<2$.

Indeed, $a_1=1<2$ and if $a_n<2$ so
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+2}<\sqrt{2+2}=2.$$
Also, $$a_{n+1}-a_n=\sqrt{2+a_n}-a_n=\frac{(2-a_n)(a_n+1)}{\sqrt{2+a_n}+a_n}>0,$$ which says that $a$ increases.

Thus, there is $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n$ and let this limit be equal to $x$.

Thus, since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function, we obtain:
$$x=\sqrt{x+2}$$ or $$x=2.$$
There is also the following way:
$$|a_n-2|=|\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}-2|=\frac{|a_{n-1}-2|}{\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}+2}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{|a_{n-1}-2|}{2}\leq\frac{|a_{n-2}-2|}{2^2}\leq...\leq\frac{|a_1-2|}{2^{n-1}}\rightarrow0,$$
which says that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=2.$$

Here, a it's a name of the sequence. Sequence its a function of a natural argument. $a_n=a(n).$ Like $\sin$ it's a name of the function $f(x)=sin{x}$ and more...

Comment: By "$a$" is bounded and "$a$ increases" you are denoting the sequence by $a$? That is somewhat confusing, generally I would assume $a$ to be the limit of the sequence.

Comment: @Math1000 $a$ is a name of the sequence. Sequence its a function of a natural argument. $a_n=a(n)$. Like $\sin$ it's a name of the function $f(x)=\sin{x}$ and more...

Comment: I suppose one could interpret it that way as well. For clarity it wouldn't hurt to include e.g. "Let $a=\{a_n : n=1,2,\ldots\}$" or "Let $a$ denote the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$."

Comment: @Math1000  I think it's clear. My teacher (B.P.Geidman RIP) said so and I very like it.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable, just that people with a different background might assume that the symbol $a$ means something else, which is why it doesn't hurt to define it explicitly.